# Executable called via ProcessBuilder can't find needed files

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, processbuilder

I've got a java servlet running to which I send a file. This file is then passed on to an executable that creates a webpage(https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter). The way I do this, is by using a ProcessBuilder. However something stranges happens...

The Potree executable is located in a directory on my PC, within this directory there is a sub folder called resources. These are resources which the Potree executable needs in order to build a webpage.

Whenever I call the potree executable via the processbuilder from the java servlet, it tells me it cannot find the resource folder:

```
    System.out.println("Creating webpage...");
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(POTREE_EXE, file.getAbsolutePath(), "-o", XAMPP_DIR, "-p", "pageName", "--overwrite");
    processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
    processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
    try {
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        p.waitFor();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I try to use the potree executable directly via CMD, it has no problem finding its resource folder. I go to the potree folder in CMD and then execute the exact same line of code as the processbuilder does. Now the executable is able to find the resource folder...

The java servlet runs on a tomcat 8.0 server...could has to do something with the fact that the processbuilder calls the executable from within a servlet which is located in the tomcat folder instead of the potree executable being executed directly from its own folder?

What exactly is going wrong here, and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! By using the `directory(File file)` method from the ProcessBuilder class, I am able to let the Potree executable run from its own directory. So I've added the line `processBuilder.directory(new File("path_to_potree_folder"));` to the above code! This way the executable has the correct working directory and can find the resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

`file.getAbsolutePath()` is fake security here: it will just append the current folder to your file if the file is a relative path.
It is not necessary unless you plan to `chdir` somewhere in your code or for accurate error messages.

You almost answered yourself:

- when running in the directory where the relative path of the file is valid, it works.

`<potree dir>
 <potree dir>/yourexecutable
 <potree dir>/resource/yourfile (file.getAbsolutePath() returns that and that's correct, file is here)`

- when running from another directory, well

`<another dir>
 <another dir>/resource/yourfile (file.getAbsolutePath() returns that and the file does not exist here)`

So you have to pass a "root folder" in a configuration file or hardcoded, from where all resource files & dirs are originated.

Always build file names from this root folder.

There are also various techniques depending on the language to compute it automatically from the launch script.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems like I've already found the solution. I guess the word I was looking for was: Working Directory. What I now do is, set the ProcessBuilders directory via the directory(File file) method. This let's the process work from within the correct directory!